# Is there a way to dynamically change field name in firebase?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

So I have this kind of structure in the firestore database

```
{
    issues: {
        issueName1: "sample opinion",
        issueName2: "sample opinion",
        ...
    }
}
```

The `issueName1` and `issueName2` represent social issues, and `sample opinion` signifies a specific persons opinion on them. Now, these issues will change overtime. Is there a way to change these field names in the firestore? Or is there a better way to structure this? I'm new to NoSQL and having a hard time grasping its concept. Thank you for any help!

Comment: I beliveve your structure is correct. You can use [Adding data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data) or [Deleting data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data) by following the official documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to how to update older documents with the new `issues`, you wouldn’t need to do that as these issues would not have an `opinion` associated with it. In NoSQL databases you don’t need to have  a consistent schema among different entries so you can just add the issues that do have an opinion.

On a side note, depending on how you are planning to retrieve the issues per person, you might want to store them all together in a map instead of individual fields:

```
{
  issues: [{
    issueName1: “sample opinion”,
    issueName3: “sample opinion”
  }]
}
```